# Fool ARM Linker to place a function code in some data memory

Tags: c++, c, linker, keil

I have a challenge in some legacy ROM code for ARM Cortex-M0

The ROM code has its data memory section and at some point it calls functions from other volatile memory via a list of function pointers.

I'm currently running out of volatile memory for the added code. The ROM code has some non-initialized data memory that are not used at all through the application lifetime.

The challenge I'm facing now is placing some of the functions into these unused data memory.

I'm using ARM C Compiler and Linker in Keil environment.

I tried creating load regions in scatter linker file, but linker objects due to overlapping sections.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your linker file is setup but you may be able to simply specify the section the function should reside:

```
extern void foo(void) __attribute__((section("rom_data")));
```

This is GCC syntax but I believe the Keil environment supports it as well.

Comment: the rom_data section is defined in ROM so that it contains only .bss and .zi parts of the data. when I try to use the attribute section, linker ignores the attribute and places it in ROM .text section